# Convert Documents (docs,pdf) to byte array in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a trouble in converting a `Documents` to `byte array`. As of now I don't have a code in it. As I'm having a trouble in finding a right solution. I only have a helper in Converting `Image` to `byte array`.

Current code in converting Image to Byte and vice versa

```
public static Image ConvertBase64ToImage(string base64String)
{
    try
    {
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        string res = base64String.Substring(base64String.IndexOf(',') + 1);
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(res);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static string ConvertImageTo64BaseString(Image image)
{
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And the Conversion

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream, true, true);
Session["userimage"] = "data:image/png;base64," + cHelper.ConvertImageTo64BaseString(img);
```

Comment: With memory streams after you fill stream with data you have to set position in code to zero before reading, otherwise, you do not get any data.

Comment: @jdweng Can you give an example of that?

Comment: ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length); ms.Position = 0;
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

Answer (score 0):

C# and .NET already support to read any file content(pdf/excel/image...) into a byte array. Look this example

**A**: `var byteArrayData = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\file\\myfile.pdf");`

Or You can also use FileStream to read all byte contents of your files.

**B**:

```
            var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (var stream = new FileStream("C:\\file\\myfile.pdf", FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int read;
                    while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    return memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.